# Is 'det' a single function?

Tags: definition, determinant

I should mention this up front: this is a question about semantics. It is extremely formal, and a bit pedantic. Most people won't care.

Is det, i.e the determinant function, a single one? Or is it multiple functions, one for each field?

Let $\mbox{Mat}(K)$ denote the set of square matrices over the field $K$ (This is nonstandard notation). Then $\det(x) \in K$ for $x\in \mbox{Mat}(K)$. So we can view $\det$ in this context as a function $\det: \mbox{Mat}(K) \rightarrow K$. If you take this view, then you are forced to acknowledge that 'det' actually refers to infinitely many functions, one for each field $K$, and that which 'det' we are referring to in a particular expression depends entirely on context.

I should note that here, we take the view that a function MUST possess a domain and codomain, that it is IS NOT just a collection of (input, output) pairs with some sort of implicit domain and codomain.

On the other hand, we may view $\det$ as a single function, taking in ANY square matrix, and returning... something. This is fine, but what would the codomain be? It would have to consist of... everything, and that is not a good codomain for a single function object. Ideally, the codomain would be a bit more expressive. However, this, formally, is not a problem.

So, which is it? The former or the latter?

Comment: Multiple functions, one for each field **and** matrix size.

Comment: Why is this a problem for the codomain, but not for the domain?  Are you sure there is a "set of all square matrices"?

Comment: I wonder if mathematicians a thousand years hence will think things like this are about the number of angels that dance on the head of a pin?

Comment: For that matter, you can also consider the determinant for matrices over a commutative ring rather than a field.  And there are various other extensions, again different functions.

Comment: We also speak of "the" identity matrix, "the" zero matrix, "the" exponential map, . . . even though these are different for every field and every matrix size.

Comment: @Bungo Why would we need a different function for each matrix size?

Comment: @saulspatz Why would there not be?

Comment: @extremeaxe5 Because the calculation is different for each matrix size.

Comment: @Bungo A function doesn’t care how it is calculated.

Comment: I'm talking about the same kind of problem as "the set of all sets."  If I recall correctly, there isn't a "set of all fields," either.  If that's so, while there is a set of all *real* square matrices, for example, there isn't a set of all square matrices over all fields.  On the other hand, if there *is* a set of all fields, then there's a set of all square matrices.  I don't see how you can say that one exists and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning that mathematicians usually implicitly have in mind is that there are lots of separate functions written "$\det$".  Specifically, for each field $K$ and each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a separate function $\det:M_n(K)\to K$ (which to be completely pedantic perhaps should be written $\det_{n,K}$, but that quickly gets unwieldy so no one does it).  Note here that $M_n(K)$ is the standard notation for the set of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $K$.

There are also many other functions that are commonly written as "$\det$".  For instance, it is very common to restrict one's attention to invertible matrices and write $\det:GL_n(K)\to K^\times$, where $GL_n(K)$ is the set of invertible $n\times n$ matrices and $K^\times$ is the set of nonzero elements of $K$.  This is of course not literally the same function as the function $\det:M_n(K)\to K$, but no one ever bothers to distinguish it notationally.

I would add that absolutely none of this is special to "$\det$".  There are oodles and oodles of similarly context-dependent notations in math; for instance, the symbol $+$ can refer to a vast variety of different binary operations, with the specific operation in any given instance usually left to be inferred from context.  Mathematical notation is meant to be understood by humans, and humans are very good at resolving ambiguity from context (and bad at processing overly cluttered but completely unambiguous notation).

Comment: Why would there be a separate function for each matrix size?

Comment: Well, ultimately it's just a matter of convention.  But normally it is not fruitful to think about the set $\bigcup_n M_n(K)$ of _all_ square matrices over $K$ at once--this set has no useful algebraic structure.  Instead, we focus on one size of square matrices at a time (since, for instance, $M_n(K)$ naturally has the structure of a ring).

Answer (score -1):

What about define it as a function with following domain and codomain 
$$
\mathrm{det}: \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\ \bigcup_{K:\ K\ \text{is a field}} M_{n\times n}(K)\to \bigcup_{K:\ K\ \text{is a field}} K
$$

Comment: Formally (treating a function as a set of ordered pairs), the determinant on $\Bbb R$ is different from the determinant on $\Bbb C$, even though $\Bbb C$ contains $\Bbb R$; simply taking the union doesn't answer the question. And fields form a proper class anyway, so I don't know that the union is even well-defined.

Comment: There are two problems with this. First of all, the classification of det here as a function mapping from a truly enormous set to another truly enormous set is not helpful. This is purely a reason from information categorization. The other problem is that you can put any objects into a set, and endow that set with some operations, and boom, you have a field. Thus, the codomain would literally contain everything in the universe of discourse.

Comment: @extremeaxe5 I am already convinced that what I wrote is not helpful and your last observation is the only reason why I will not delete this post. It was really funny :)

Comment: You know what, as bad as this answer is, the more I read it the more I like it.  I think there is a real point you can make with this:  look at all the crazy gymnastics you have to go through in order to make a single $\mathrm{det}$ function for all $n$ and all $K$.  It's just silly and fraught with logic problems.  This is nearly an answer to OP's question.